# Trying to install nngt library, but keep getting this: Getting requirements to build wheel ... error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to get access to the nngt library and i followed the installing instructions (https://nngt.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.1/user/install.html)
I installed numpy/scipy/networkx/igraph and tryed "pip install nngt". But it always gets stuck on the same error and the wheel can't be build. I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. I've also tried it with conda but got the same issue.

This is my output (nearly starting at the error as it is quite long):

```
      copying .\nngt\generation\func_connect.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\nngt\generation
      copying .\nngt\geometry\README.md -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\nngt\geometry
      copying .\nngt\plot\chord_diag\README.md -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\nngt\plot\chord_diag
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 110, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\normal\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
          _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jk_r_gri\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4gmqa8en\nngt_02616bb414ae4d3b9f5deae39b6768be\.\setup.py", line 91, in build_extensions
          if re.match(r"gcc|g\+\+|mingw|clang", c):
        File "C:\Users\tim.voelcker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 190, in match
          return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for NNGT
Failed to build NNGT
ERROR: Could not build wheels for NNGT, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Well i feel like there are some dependencies missing but i can't find out which as i installed everything, what was mentioned on their site. I've also tried upgrading the "pip setuptools wheel".

Sorry if formatting isn't on point. First post here and didn't know how to make the output in a better format. If anything is missing just let me know. Thanks for any help